# Pear Excel Writer: how to assign leading zeros to column?

Tags: php, excel, pear, export-to-excel

There's a section in my website that allows to export an Excel file by clicking a button. The data displayed in the Excel file is taken from my database using SQL.

The following are examples of what is found in the column in my database:

```
12
34
456
2
7654
43
1234
7
```

Currently it displays identically as above in the Excel sheet, but what I would like would be for all the rows to have 4 digits. Therefore, data with less than 4 digits would have leading zeros added to it.

Using the same example, here is how I would like it to show in the exported Excel sheet:

```
0012
0034
0456
0002
7654
0043
1234
0007
```

This seems like a relatively simple task, but I cant seem to find how to make this happen through my research. I hope someone here will be able to help.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to make sure that the column /data type for the column is text, otherwise the value will be treated as a number, which strips the leading zeros

Comment: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-format.setnumformat.php  assuming this is the library you're using (which you shouldn't be. this is a dead project).

Comment: Yup, afaik it's no longer maintained. This may be a better alternative: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number = str_pad($value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: interesting! I'm a beginner programmer so its difficult for me to interpret what to do without context but this definitely looks like it will work.